# c++ template custom warning

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, warnings

I'm working with C++11 and i have some code which is equivalent to

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto add_func( const T1& lhs, const T2& rhs )
{
    return lhs + rhs;
}
```

when I compile this code using `float` and `int` as `T1` and `T2` respectively I get warnings mentioning that the conversion might cause some loss of data, which is natural.

My problem is that every instance of this warning will point to the line `return lhs + rhs;` which makes the warning pretty much useless.

Is there a way (ideally a portable way) to re-throw these warning where the function is called instead of inside the template?

i'm working with Visual Studio 2012 but a portable way would be preferable

EDIT:

To be more clear: I know this warning is correct and is caused by a misuse of this code, the issue is that i would like the compiler to find for me the places where such a misuse is done. Right now, if this warning appears, I have to validate by hand each call to `add_func`, that does not seem very maintainable to me.

I hope this makes more sense now

Comment: Is the function definition complete? Are you using C++14's return type deduction for normal functions, or did you forget to write the trailing return type?

Comment: this is not the complete type functions since i use a custom template struct to specify the corresponding return type. The actual return type is picked by a meta-function from one of the two available types. i can add the actual return type but i'm not sure it is relevant.

Comment: Well, I think you should be focusing on the reason why you get the warning in the first place. If you have a warning, there's likely something wrong - but what is possibly wrong is not shown in your question

Comment: the warning is in the correct position I think. Adding `int` to `float` is not the issue. It is returning a `float` as `int` (probably)

Comment: I edited the question since I seem to have been misunderstood, the problem is that i do not know where "the reason why i get the warning in the first place" actually is...

Comment: The warning depends totally on the compiler used, but you do not say which one. For example GCC does tell you where the template is instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooking into the compiler's warning system seems like a non-starter to me. Instead, it seems like we just need to find more information about the warning.

I assume you are building inside of Visual Studio. If so, switch from the Error List to the Output window and you should see something like the following:

```
1>add_fun.cpp(31): warning C4244: 'return' : conversion from 'const float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>          add_fun.cpp(38) : see reference to function template instantiation 'T1 add_func<int,float>(const T1 &,const T2 &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T1=int,
1>              T2=float
1>          ]
```

The operative line here is the "add_fun.cpp(38) : see reference to function template instantiation", which tell you where the template is being instantiated.

This is Visual C++-specific, but most compilers should include similar information in the full error test.

Comment: It's a sort of stacktrace for template instantiation :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is no simple way to resolve your problem. This issue is the real pain for the generation of developers using C++ templates meta-programming. You can see exactly the same warnings pointing in the very guts of STL when they are generated for standard algorithms, for example.

But as [c45207](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2392683/c45207) properly [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16684583/261217), one may still find the source of a warning since the actual calling line is specified in the compiler's output. And I believe a C++ developer should be familiar with this when working with templates.